# transparent background node webkit window

Tags: transparency, node-webkit

I can do almost everything else with nwjs so I find my failure to make this work very frustrating.

I have made the simplest of html file with `<body style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);"></body>` and `"transparent":true,` in the window section of package.json, but the window background remains white.

(I have a new Dell tablet PC running windows 8.1.)

Something I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

@chris .... quick check -- do you have your Windows "Theme" set to an "Aero" type, which allows for transparency?  I'm not sure on Windows 8.1, but on 7 the "standard" desktop themes don't allow for transparency (shadowed, rounded elements)  whereas the Aero desktop theme(s) do.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. Tried [link](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-unlock-the-hidden-aero-lite-theme-in-windows-8-1/) how-to-unlock-the-hidden-aero-lite-theme-in-windows-8-1 but no luck with nwjs transparency yet; will try harder tomorrow!